# Eliminating some questions from the unanswered queue by upvoting using data query

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, data-explorer

I am using [this data query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/119994/zero-score-answers-to-unanswered-questions-by-tag) provided by [user75064](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/75064/75064),ˈjuː.zɚ79365, [40 votes](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/85506) and Lord Farin to upvote *some answers with no upvotes* but actually address some/all concerns of OP.

The data query is looking for question marked as unanswered, with no upvoted answer, under a specific tag, for e.g. [pde](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pde).

While I was doing this earlier this evening, I found that actually some of the questions obtained through this query actually had an upvoted answer. For example:

[Proving an identity regarding the Cauchy problem (using convolutions)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400546/proving-an-identity-regarding-the-cauchy-problem-using-convolutions)

[sobolev spaces - product of two functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398686/sobolev-spaces-product-of-two-functions)

[Writing a 2nd order PDE as a system of equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396652/writing-a-2nd-order-pde-as-a-system-of-equations)

[partial differential equation $y^2\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x\partial y} + \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial y^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389504/partial-differential-equation-y2-frac-partial-2-u-partial-x-partial-y)

[canonical form for hyperbolic PDE $y^2u_{xx}+2xyu_{xy}+u_{yy}=0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378129/canonical-form-for-hyperbolic-pde-y2u-xx2xyu-xyu-yy-0)

[Find all solutions of the 1-D heat equation of a specific form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352618/find-all-solutions-of-the-1-d-heat-equation-of-a-specific-form)

Then I was going to edit the query, and found there is nothing wrong with the predicate:

```
p.AcceptedAnswerID IS NULL AND
p.ClosedDate IS NULL AND
p.Score >= 0 AND
a.Score = 0 AND
a.Score >= ALL
```

Is this a bug of the SE data explorer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Data Explorer does not have real-time data. You can see the date stamp of the latest data dump on [its frontpage](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Given the visibility of the query, it is likely that someone was using it (with the same or different tag parameter, since tags overlap) since the last data dump was generated.

Possible solutions: (a) pick a different tag; (b) pick a different time interval of the query results; (c) use a search such as `is:answer score:0 [pde]` (which is real-time, but will also find zero-score answers to questions that have other, upvoted, answers.).

Comment: Nice, they aren't on the list anymore as of now.